# How to apply a function / map values of each element in a 2d numpy array/matrix?

Tags: numpy

Given the following numpy matrix:

```
import numpy as np
mymatrix = np.matrix('-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -4 0 4')


matrix([[-1,  0,  1],
        [-2,  0,  2],
        [-4,  0,  4]])
```

and the following function (sigmoid/logistic):

```
import math
def myfunc(z):
    return 1/(1+math.exp(-z))
```

I want to get a new NumPy array/matrix where each element is the result of applying the `myfunc` function to the corresponding element in the original matrix.

the `map(myfunc, mymatrix)` fails because it tries to apply myfunc to the rows not to each element. I tried to use `numpy.apply_along_axis` and `numpy.apply_over_axis` but they are meant also to apply the function to rows or columns and not on an element by element basis.

So how can apply `myfunc(z)` to each element of `myarray` to get:

```
matrix([[ 0.26894142,  0.5       ,  0.73105858],
        [ 0.11920292,  0.5       ,  0.88079708],
        [ 0.01798621,  0.5       ,  0.98201379]])
```

Answer (score 84):

Apparently, the way to apply a function to elements is to convert your function into a vectorized version that takes arrays as input and return arrays as output.

You can easily convert your function to vectorized form using `numpy.vectorize` as follows:

```py
myfunc_vec = np.vectorize(myfunc)
result = myfunc_vec(mymatrix)
```

or for a one shot usage:

```py
np.vectorize(myfunc)(mymatrix)
```

As pointed out by @Divakar, it's better (performance-wise) if you can write an already vectorized function from scratch (using NumPy built [ufuncs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) without using `numpy.vectorize`) like so:

```py
def my_vectorized_func(m):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-m))  # np.exp() is a built-in ufunc

my_vectorized_func(mymatrix)
```

Since [`numpy.exp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html#numpy.exp) is already vectorized (and `math.exp` wasn't) the whole expression `1/(1+np.exp(-m))` will be vectorized (and faster that applying my original function to each element).

The following complete example produced the required output:

```
import numpy as np
mymatrix = np.matrix('-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -4 0 4')
import math
def myfunc(z):
    return 1/(1+math.exp(-z))

np.vectorize(myfunc)(mymatrix) # ok, but slow

def my_vectorized_func(m):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-m))

my_vectorized_func(mymatrix) # faster using numpy built-in ufuncs
```

Comment: For performance, you should be using NumPy ufuncs - `1/(1+np.exp(-mymatrix))`.

Comment: I revised my answer to include a version that use the built in numpy.exp  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this helps, scipy has a [sigmoid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html) function you can directly call on a matrix.