# How can I use a dictionary to transform an array in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

As a toy example let's say that I have:

```
import numpy as np

np.array([['dog','sheep','sheep','dog','cat'], 
          ['dog','dog','sheep','cat','cat']])
dict = {'dog':5,'cat':1,'sheep':3}
```

I want to find an efficient way to construct the desired array where I replaced the elements according to the dictionary.

(The real dictionary is the periodic table and the real array has thousands of elements)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a function / map values of each element in a 2d numpy array/matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594695/how-to-apply-a-function-map-values-of-each-element-in-a-2d-numpy-array-matrix)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `vectorize` the dict's `get` method.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([['dog','sheep','sheep','dog','cat'], 
...               ['dog','dog','sheep','cat','cat']])
>>> d = {'dog':5,'cat':1,'sheep':3}
>>> 
>>> np.vectorize(d.get)(a)
array([[5, 3, 3, 5, 1],
       [5, 5, 3, 1, 1]])
```

I have renamed `dict` to `d` because you should not shadow the builtin name `dict` with your own variables.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this? This replaces the values before creating the `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
my_dict = {'dog': 5, 'cat': 1, 'sheep': 3}

np.array([
    [my_dict[e] for e in ['dog','sheep','sheep','dog','cat']],
    [my_dict[e] for e in ['dog','dog','sheep','cat','cat']],
])
```

Or do you need something more generalized?